# Recursive JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin after installing Java for OS X 2013-005

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start, osx-mavericks, java-6

After installing [Java for OS X 2013-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572) update for Mavericks, I follow [this Re-enable article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559?viewlocale=en_US) to re-enable Java 1.6 but noticed something quite wrong. Problem is that whenever I verify Java with [javatester](http://www.javatester.org/version.html), I always see empty box without anything. So I double check the steps in Re-enable article and found that at step number 4:

```
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

The folder JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin is just containing a series of itself:

```
/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/**JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin**/Contents/Resources/**JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin**/Contents/Resources/**JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin**/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin/Contents/Resources/**JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin**/...<it goes on>
```

This thing doesn't look right for me. Since the Re-enable article is quite confusing, does anyone know which step did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you're trying to run an applet using the Java plugin.
However, Apple has removed the plugin since Java for OS X 2012-006.
Quote from the very Apple support page you've linked to:

> "this update disables the Java SE 6 applet plug-in"

So if you want to be able to run applets within a browser, you'll need to install Java 7 from Oracle instead.